# issue in match a word in string

Tags: php, regex

I have used the following code to match a word in string but had some issue.

```
$string='Hi how are u am fine and where are you'; 
$shop = array( array( Title => "no",),array( Title => "block",),array( Title => "How",));
foreach($shop as $t=>$v)
    {
        foreach($v as $n)
        {   
            if((preg_match("/\b^([^\s]*)$|" . $n . "\b/i",$string)))                
            {
                $match='Y';
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
```

case:1 `$string='block'` works fine;

case:2 `$string='words block'` works fine;

case:3 `$string='block word'` doesn't work.

Please find the error and someone help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you please provide more specific explanation?

Comment: You also have to tell us what the value of `$n` is.

Comment: @mapek more like what `$t` is

Comment: $shop = array( array( Title => "no",),array( Title => "block",),array( Title => "How",)); and my $n= noblockhow

Comment: When the string starts with any of my word in shop then i dont get the $match as Y in other cases i get the output.

Comment: Try [`$re = '/^([^\s]*)$|\b' . $n . '\b/i';`](https://ideone.com/i8hDT4).

Comment: @stribizhev  thank u very much for the solution i have tried but i dont get the ans. pls provide me some other solution.

Comment: Please share the IDEONE demo showing your code is not working. Also, specify exact requirements. My current demo shows a match for your 3rd `string`.

Comment: @stribizhev thank u i have just added trim infront of $n now i got the answer.

Comment: Like `$re = '/^([^\s]*)$|\b' . trim($n) . '\b/i';`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might need to rethink your approach to the regex pattern building. However, the current one has a problem: you define it inside a double quoted string literal where a backslash is used to introduce escape sequences. To really match a word boundary, you need to use double backslashes (i.e. `"/\\bHow\\b/"` will match a whole word `How`, and `"/\bHow\b/"` match a backspace character, *How* and a backspace character).

Besides, `\b` word boundary also matches at the beginning of a string. No point using `\b^` - this is ambiguous. I think you are trying to match any non-whitespace string first, and then a specific whole word.

Use:

```
$re = '/^([^\s]*)$|\b' . trim($n) . '\b/i';
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/i8hDT4) showing Y for `$string='block word'`.